# Construct own message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have **user** table, which is obviously does not outbox table. Table consist **uuid** and **email** field. I need to construct message and publish into Kafka based on this two field with next format:

```
{
  "uuid": "11ebe013-ffd2-4523-b6b4-6318cbe7e6d1",
  "email": "jaron24@example.net",
  "staticObject": {
     "staticProperty1": "WEB",
     "staticProperty2": "random.com"
  },
 "staticProperty": "CREATED"
}
```

I don't want to create new field in table, where I can put constructed message(parameter **transforms.outbox.table.field.event.payload** - not suitable for this case). I want that kafka-connect construct it(with schema above) for me.

Is there any possibility to achieve this via configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [New Record State Extraction](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.1/transformations/event-flattening.html)?